# How to display the seek bar on youtube angular-youtube-embed directive?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

When a youtube video is being played if I mouse over the player as expected the seek bar is shown. After a few seconds it disappears even if I keep the mouse over the player.

What I need to do is trigger this animation elsewhere in my code (i.e. the seek bar showing and then disappearing).

Is this possible?

Comment: I am also wanting to do this in my app, if anyone can help